# Installing Catalyst 11.6  for an ATI HD 6970

Tags: 10.10, installation, ati, deb, radeon

Ubuntu Maverick 10.10 is displaying the desktop okay (though limited to 1600x1200) after my having installed my new HD 6970 card, so I'm now trying to install the proprietary driver (I understand the open source one requires a more recent kernel than that in Maverick).

The proprietary driver under 'Additional Drivers' resulted in a black screen on boot, so I deactivated and am trying to follow the manual install instructions at the [cchtml Ubuntu Maverick Installation Guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Maverick_Installation_Guide#Installing_the_drivers_manually).

When I try to create the .deb packages with:

```
sh ati-driver-installer-11-6-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/maverick
```

I get:

```
david@skipper:~/catalyst11.6$ sh ati-driver-installer-11-6-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/maverick
Created directory fglrx-install.oLN3ux
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing ATI Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver-8.861.........................
=====================================================================
 ATI Technologies Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager
=====================================================================
Generating package: Ubuntu/maverick
Package build failed!
Package build utility output:
./packages/Ubuntu/ati-packager.sh: 396: debclean: not found
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor):
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:8.861-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by ATI Technologies Inc. <http://ati.amd.com/support/driver.html>
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.64Vzxk
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules build
Can't exec "debian/rules": Permission denied at /usr/bin/dpkg-buildpackage line 507.
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build failed with unknown exit code -1
Cleaning in directory .
/usr/bin/fakeroot: line 176: debian/rules: Permission denied
debuild: fatal error at line 1319:
couldn't exec fakeroot debian/rules:
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor):
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:8.861-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by ATI Technologies Inc. <http://ati.amd.com/support/driver.html>
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.QEmIld
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules build
Can't exec "debian/rules": Permission denied at /usr/bin/dpkg-buildpackage line 507.
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build failed with unknown exit code -1
Cleaning in directory .
Can't exec "debian/rules": Permission denied at /usr/bin/debuild line 1314.
debuild: fatal error at line 1313:
couldn't exec debian/rules: Permission denied
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor):
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:8.861-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by ATI Technologies Inc. <http://ati.amd.com/support/driver.html>
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.xtY6vC
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules build
Can't exec "debian/rules": Permission denied at /usr/bin/dpkg-buildpackage line 507.
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build failed with unknown exit code -1
Cleaning in directory .
/usr/bin/fakeroot: line 176: debian/rules: Permission denied
debuild: fatal error at line 1319:
couldn't exec fakeroot debian/rules:
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor):
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
dpkg-buildpackage: source package fglrx-installer
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2:8.861-0ubuntu1
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by ATI Technologies Inc. <http://ati.amd.com/support/driver.html>
 dpkg-source --before-build fglrx.oYWICI
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 debian/rules build
Can't exec "debian/rules": Permission denied at /usr/bin/dpkg-buildpackage line 507.
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build failed with unknown exit code -1
Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.oLN3ux
```

I've installed `devscripts` which has `debclean` in it.

I've tried running the command with and without `sudo`.

I'm not experienced with installing from downloads/source, but it seems like the file `debian/source` isn't being set to be executable when it needs to be. If I extract only, without using the package builder command, debian/rules is 744.

As to what to do next, I'm stumped.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never had success generating a .deb package with the ATI's installer. Apparently you can have some pretty weird problems if you install fglrx (ATI's driver) along side the open source one - though I've only read that, not sure what those problems really are.

You may want to make sure you aren't loading the open source ATI driver - you'll want to add "radeon" to some blacklist file in /etc/modules/, reboot and use "lsmod | grep radeon" to confirm it's not getting loaded. Then I'd re-try the driver installer, but I'd have it install directly in to your system, as, like I said, I've never managed to get the .deb generating working (though maybe that's easy, just perhaps requires some package, etc?).

There's some pretty epic guides out there to dealing with being an ATI vicitm on Linux, if you're still stuck, I suggest you look for them. (I used to love ATI, but their cards just seem so difficult to get running really well in Linux lately.. Hopefully AMD changes that soon!)

Comment: I tried having the installer install directly as you suggested (`sh ati-driver-installer-11-6-x86.x86_64.run`) and it seems it's worked fine! Thanks!

Comment: @David Oliver - Glad to hear it! Happy Computing!