# AMD 11.12 driver issue

Tags: drivers, command-line, ati

I followed the steps letter by letter in this post... [Gnome 3.2 problems in the shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73615/gnome-3-2-problems-in-the-shell)

However I have come to a problem that I don't know how to solve...  It is saying that package build has failed and it could not process the .deb file.  I would like to install this as it increases performance of Unity.  I have an ATi Mobility HD4250 Graphics Card.  I also have been using the drivers that came out of the box with Unity, didn't install the ones from the Additional Drivers list..

[image: my terminal]

Now after all of that, it says it can't open the driver installer.
[image]

Ok now with this new driver installed, everything appears to be choppy...  It didn't do that with the drivers that came in Unity.  I thought these were supposed to be an improvement?

Comment: Now that I see it, its a different driver.  Do I want to go with 11.12 or 12.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some packages to be able to build your drivers, please install them before trying to rebuild the drivers again. Open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
```

After these are installed you can then execute `sh ./amd-driver-installer-12-1-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/oneiric` to build the packages and `sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb` to install them.

Please make sure that any old version of the drivers is already removed from the system

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

will remove any previous installed versions at the moment in your system, dont worry if they give faults, just move on.

For a complete step by step guide on how to remove / revert / install the AMD driver visit this post

- [Is my ATI graphics card supported in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu)

Comment: How would I be able to check if I have any drivers still installed?  I did the step from the previous question before anything.

Comment: I meant I did the very first step in the last question where to remove all the fglrx drivers installed.  Is that good enough?

Comment: Edited to include steps (also its also part of the post I linked) to remove the driver. Btw, what card do you have?

Comment: Now it says it can't execute the driver installer.

Comment: ATI Mobility Radeon HD4250       sh: Can't open ./amd-driver-installer-12-1-x86.x86_64.run

Comment: Well what I have downloaded is 11-12 driver but I guess what you said was to install 12-1?

Comment: That explains it, you can choose the 11-12 or the 12-1, does not matter they are both good, just make sure that the correct file is downloaded and the executable bit is set. Have a look at the **Official ATI binaries from the ATI site** section of the linked post.

Comment: Thank you I got everything up and running nice and smoothly! :)

Comment: Yes everything is up and running!  Just had to tweak a couple of settings in CCSM in order to do it.

Comment: Just one more question...  This added a bunch of files to my Home directory.  Can I move them anywhere to clean it up or do they have to stay there?

Comment: use `sudo rm filename` to remove files you cannot delete with your user. Do it one by one, all of the files newly created + the ones you downloaded. be extra careful once you `rm` one file that is gone for ever. Or as an option you can open a nautilus windows with sudo privileges using `gksudo nautilus`, navigate to the files and just press delete, they will go to the trash.

Comment: ok will do.  Is it also common that Ubuntu gets slower to bootup login to the Unity DE after installing this?

Comment: I would notice only a minor pause when loading the kernel module, nothing serious, if you think might be another issue please let us know by creating another question.

Comment: Oh no there's no problem, I too noticed the slight pause as well  I'm not concerned about it just seeing if someone noticed it too.  Anyways thanks for the help!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50771/installing-catalyst-11-6-for-an-ati-hd-6970) thread useful

"I tried having the installer install directly as you suggested (sh ati-driver-installer-11-6-x86.x86_64.run) and it seems it's worked fine! Thanks!"